# jQuery Replacing all hyphens by line breaks

Tags: jquery

Simply put, I want to replace hyphens in a certain ID with line-breaks.

After a lot of searching and trying, I made my own fiddle and it works like expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/yj460ua5/

HTML:

```
<div id="titel-sr">
  <h2 class="sdfsdf-sdfsdfs-sdfsdfssss-ffff sdfsd-ffsf-ffs">
       This is a title - This is the colour - dsssfsdf - asdf
  </h2>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#titel-sr').html(function(i,v) {
        return v.replace(/-/g, '<br />');
    });
});
```

It works exactly how I want it, but somehow in Wordpress the HTML within the H2 gets replaced instead of the actual text I want replaced.

So I am getting an output like this (notice not even all hyphens get replaced):

```
<div id="titel-sr">
<h2 class="title<br />heading<br />center fusion<br />responsive<br />typography<br />calculated fusion-responsive-typography-calculated" 
style="margin: 0px; --fontSize:44; line-height: 1.26;" data<br="" data-fontsize="44" data-lineheight="55.44px">fontsize="44" data<br>lineheight="55.44px"&gt;
Shopping Center – Somewhere – Amsterdam</h2>
</div>
```

I would be very grateful if you have the answer for me!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about doing `$('#titel-sr h2').html` ? Also this `but somehow in Wordpress the HTML ` is not true since the issue has nothing to do with Wordpress

Comment: Then nothing gets replaced, weirdly enough

Comment: So this is not working http://jsfiddle.net/0g6rx7kz/

Comment: Indeed, that doesn't replace any hyphens

Comment: In the jsfiddle I linked before how is that not working?

Comment: That is the problem, it SHOULD work, but yet somehow it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever encounters this:

I eventualy gave up on trying it with jQuery, so I tried it with PHP.

```
<?php echo str_replace(' - ', '<br />', get_the_title()); ?>
```

Did the trick.